# Compare two lists of numbers in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

So, I can do this (using cl):

```
(loop for x in my-list
      for y in my-other-list
      if (> x y) return t
      if (< x y) return nil)
```

But I really feel like this should be as easy as `(list> my-list my-other-list)` But I can find absolutely no evidence that this function exists by any name. In fact, I can't even find any general documentation for comparing lists *at all*. This makes me feel like I must be missing something.

Do I have do define `(list>)` myself, or have I missed great swaths of documentation in my haste and confusion?

And if I have to define it myself, can you do a better job? I'm not really an elisp hacker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
(require 'cl)
(every '> my-list my-other-list)
```

Comment: That is definitely superior to mine, thanks! But also: I'm taking this as evidence that I'm not crazy-blind regarding the core lisp function documentation?

Comment: Sure. I wouldn't necessarily expect to have a predefined `list<` function since it so easy to do this way. There's also ambiguity over whether a `list<` function would be equivalent to the results of `some`, `every`, or simply `mapcar*`.

Comment: Reasonable, and while I disagree about the potential ambiguity (I think that people would expect it to apply to the whole list--hence not `some`--and for it to behave have like all the other boolean functions and return a single value, not a list--hence not like `mapcar*`. But the utility of every makes me feel like this is, if anything, a documentation and not a language failing.

Comment: Note that this version is *not* suitable as a sorting predicate, in case that's what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The order relations are not the same!  The order relation described in the question is the lexicographic order of lists, while the answer speaks of a coordinatewise order.  For example the lists '(2 1) and  '(1 2) will cause one order to return true, and the other, false.

Comment: Change `every` to `some` and I believe it will be the same.

Comment: I guess not.  Check what happens for the pair of lists `'(1 2 3)` and `'(2 1 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest Elisp provides is probably `version-list-<`.